# How to use \href command with \StrSubstitute?

Tags: xstring, email, href

I am facing difficulty to get the outputs
First i want to replace a character "_" in the email id called ab_c@email.com
for which i used `\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\textunderscore}` and second to get hyperlink for email i used `\href` but both these two commands do not work simultaneously. So how can achived so that i can replace and fet hyperlink.
Below is my MWE which i tried so far.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\Email}[1]{
 Email: \href{\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\textunderscore}}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\textunderscore}}
}

\begin{document}

  \Email{ab_c@email.com}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to do the substitution in the first argument; next, you can't use `\StrSubstitute` *in* the argument.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\Email}[1]{%
 Email: %
 \StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\textunderscore}[\temp]%
 \href{mailto:#1}{\temp}%
}

\begin{document}

  \Email{ab_c@example.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't forget to protect the end of lines.

Comment: Its working. How can remove the border line which comes up around the email ID @egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron I get no border, because I don't use Adobe Acrobat Reader. It's added by some PDF viewers.

Comment: Ok, it may depending upon the application which we used. Thank you so much @egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron I guess you can remove it with `\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}`

Comment: Yes, also we can use the option as `hidelinks` as `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` @egreg